# Authorization of user - Assigning user a Authorization Policy .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, razor, authorization

So when this code runs, the user gets authenticated and I see they have the associated claims I provided them. However, they are not authorized to view any pages because they dont have the correct AuthorizationPolicy. I thought that giving them the role of "Court User" and authenticating them would give them the "Court_Users" AuthorizationPolicy by default since that meets the requirements, but its not working as such.

How do I assign a user an Authorization Policy they meet the requirements for once they have been Authenticatied?

Startup Page:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Shared/login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Shared/login";
    });
            services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/NonCourt_Users","Non Court User");
                options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Court_Users","Court_Users");
                options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Shared");
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Court_Users", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                                .RequireClaim("role", "Court User")
                                                .Build());
                options.AddPolicy("NonCourt_Users", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                                .RequireClaim("role", "Non Court User")
                                                .Build());
            });
```

Login Page:

```
                         var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);

                            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, User.EmailAddress));
                            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, User.Name.First_Name));

                            if (User.CourtUser)
                            {
                                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Court User"));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Non Court User"));
                            }
                            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                            {
                                AllowRefresh = true,
                                ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60),
                                IsPersistent = true
                            };

                            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(principal), authProperties);

                            HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("CurrentUser", User);

                            clearSession();
```

Comment: If you're using IdentityServer4 you'll have to add your ApiScope to the policy and then your scope to the claim

Answer (score 1):

```
if (User.CourtUser)
{
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Court User"));
}
else
{
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Non Court User"));
}
```

As Gordon Khanh Ng said, in the login page, if you are adding the claims using the `ClaimTypes.Role` type, in the Startup Page, you should use the same type to set the  policy, code as below:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Contact");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/NonCourt_Users", "NonCourt_Users");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Court_Users", "Court_Users");
        });

        #region snippet1
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie();
        #endregion
         
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Court_Users", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                            .RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Court User")
                                            .Build());
            options.AddPolicy("NonCourt_Users", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                            .RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Non Court User")
                                            .Build());
        });
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    }
```

[Note]Please note the policy name when you set the razor page conventions.

Then, if you want to get the claim, you should also use the same type name:

```
@page
@model CookieSample.Pages.Court_Users.CourtUserManageIndexModel
 
@using System.Security.Claims

@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Court User Manage Index"; }

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2> 

<h2>@User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "FullName")?.Value</h2>
<h2>@User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)?.Value</h2>
```

The result as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I did make that change, but that didnt solve the issue for me. Im still not understand though, where does the user get assigned that authorization policy? They are still getting locked out of pages because they dont have the authorizationpolicy even though they meet the criteria for it?

Comment: Try to remove the ` HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("CurrentUser", User); clearSession();` in the login page. Based on your code, you are setting your application to use cookie authentication, so, after login success, the user identity information (include the user claims) will store in the cookie, then, in the next request, you can find the user information from the HttpContext.User. Please check your Startup.cs file, have you set the cookie/session expired time? make sure it is not expired.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your condition right, then that's must be some misunderstood here...

On the login page, you set the cookie with `ClaimTypes.Role`, which represent the string `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role`. But on the policy, it turns out `RequireClaim("role", "Court User")`... I think yout might want to take a look.

Beside, if you use the `Authorize` attribute, make sure to specify the corresponding policy. Then that should be good.

Comment: I tried switching the RequireClaim("role", "Court User") piece to uppercase "Role" and it didnt change anything. 

options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Court_Users","Court_Users") the second parameter specifies which policy is required. Can you please elaborate further, Im not understanding why this is not correct.

Comment: I mean you should try `RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Court User")`, not just replace the upper case... `ClaimTypes.Role` represent a complete difference string as I mention above